# what is the use of "ように" in this sentence

Tags: grammar

男児が鯉のように川の流れを遡る力を持つようにという願いを象徴したものです。

i understand the usage of the first ように but i cant understand the usage of the second. at first i thought it could be the ように that means "in order to, so that", but im not sure about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right that this ように means "so that." In fact, it is the same one used in ようにする. Your example sentence can be rewritten something like:

> 男児が鯉のように川の流れを遡る力を持つ**ようにしてほしい**という願いを象徴したものです。

So「鯉のように川の流れを遡る力を持つようにという願い」means "wish to possess the power to go river upstream like Koi fish." Hope it makes sense!